# Sorting XML files

Tags: python, xml, xslt, sorting, xpath

Is it possible to sort XML files like the following:

```
<model name="ford">
<driver>Bob</driver>
<driver>Alice</driver>
</model>

<model name="audi">
<driver>Carly</driver>
<driver>Dean</driver>
</model>
```

Which would become

```
<model name="audi">
<driver>Carly</driver>
<driver>Dean</driver>
</model>

<model name="ford">
<driver>Alice</driver>
<driver>Bob</driver>
</model>
```

That is, the outermost elements are sorted first, then the second outermost, and so on.

They'd need to be sorted by element name first.

Comment: Read the structure into a list of objects, sort it, then write it back wherever you want. It's that simple. I don't think people over here will write code for you.

Comment: I was hoping there was something out there that can already do it. It would save reinventing the wheel.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to sort a xml, but you can use xslt to transform it. [see this](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_sort.asp)

Comment: to answer your question, yes it is possible. it can be done :) `hint: ` either use lxml or ElementTree

Comment: XML is just a data structure. There is a plethora of sorting functions like `.sort()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a refinement of Kirill's solution, I think it better reflects the stated requirements, and it avoids the type error XSLT 2.0 will give you if the sort key contains more than one value (but it still works on 1.0).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" />

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
      <xsl:sort select="(@name | text())[1]"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi, is there a typo in the xslt: <xsl:apply-templates> needs to be a starting tag, not a complete tag (the matching end tag is two lines lower in the file)

Answer (score 1):

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()">
      <xsl:sort select="text() | @*"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It works, but only by accident, and looks more general than it is. It only works, for example, because elements with child elements have exactly one attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to sort the entire xml dom.
Instead take the required nodes into a list and sort them. Because we would need the sorted order while processing and not in file, its better done in run time.
May be like this, using minidom.

```py
import os, sys
from xml.dom import minidom
document = """\
<root>
<model name="ford">
<driver>Bob</driver>
<driver>Alice</driver>
</model><model name="audi">
<driver>Carly</driver>
<driver>Dean</driver>
</model>
</root>
"""

document = minidom.parseString(document)
elements = document.getElementsByTagName("model")
elements.sort(key=lambda elements:elements.attributes['name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort nodes by removing them from the parent node, and re-inserting them in the intended order. For example:

```
def sort_tree(tree):
    """ recursively sorts the given etree in place """
    for child in tree:
        sort_tree(child)

    sorted_children = sorted(tree, key=lambda n: n.text)
    for child in tree:
        tree.remove(child)
    for child in reversed(sorted_children):
        tree.insert(0, child)

tree = etree.fromstring(YOUR_XML)
sort_tree(tree)
print(etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True))
```

Comment: I'm so impressed with this solution. I had to change this to suit new Python3 behaviour and add extra sorting axes: `sorted_children = sorted(tree, key=lambda n: n.get('name', n.get('text', n.get('value', ''))).lower())`.