# python + libxml2: Sorting XML node's elements according to attribute's value

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml, libxml2

I have the following node in an XML-document:

```
<state>
    <soso value="3"/>
    <good value="1"/>
    <bad value="2"/>
    <unknown value="0"/>
</state>
```

I need to sort its elements according to the `value` attribute's value, so that the result is the following:

```
<state>
    <unknown value="0"/>
    <good value="1"/>
    <bad value="2"/>
    <soso value="3"/>
</state>
```

How would one do it in python using libxml2?

Comment: Have you solved the issue? Did the answer help?

Comment: Yes, I did. I can't tell you how though; it's been too long ago. The requirement was to use libxml2 since lxml was not available on the system. I'm sorry for not responding earlier.

Answer (score 3):

You can sort the children of a `state` tag using `lxml` this way:

```
from lxml import etree

data = """
<state>
    <soso value="3"/>
    <good value="1"/>
    <bad value="2"/>
    <unknown value="0"/>
</state>
"""

state = etree.fromstring(data)
state[:] = sorted(state, key=lambda x: int(x.attrib.get('value')))
print etree.tostring(state)
```

Prints:

```
<state>
    <unknown value="0"/>
    <good value="1"/>
    <bad value="2"/>
    <soso value="3"/>
</state>
```

Note that it really sounds like applying an `XSLT` transformation is more logical and simple here, see:

- [Sorting XML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610731/sorting-xml-files)

See also:

- [LXML - Sorting Tag Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385358/lxml-sorting-tag-order)